# empty dataframe when appending a list to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm sure this has either been asked before or there is a really simple answer to this, but I'm having a hard time troubleshooting this and finding my exact problem.

I have the following code that is basically scraping a table (its actually taking data from a text document that was created out of html) and I'm essentially trying to make an exact replica of the table. The inner for loop should make a list from the first row, append it to a pandas dataframe, and then move onto the second row and replace the values of the list with the values of the new rows and repeat.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # imports BeautifulSoup
import pandas # imports pandas
#df=pandas.Dataframe("listname")

#Imports the text file and saves it as a variable
def read_file():
    file = open('Detroit.txt')
    data = file.read()
    file.close()
    return data

#Converts the text file into something the
soup = BeautifulSoup(read_file(),'lxml')

tables = soup.find_all(class_="overthrow table_container") #Creates a resutset that will show all of the tables with this class name
find_table = tables[2].tbody #creates a tag element from the desired table and highlights the tbody section
rows = find_table.find_all("tr") #creates another resultset signle out the elements with a tr tag.

list_of_rows = []
df = pandas.DataFrame()

for j in range(len(rows)):
    row_finder = rows[j]
    tag_row = row_finder.find_all("td")
    for i in range(len(tag_row)):
        list_of_rows.insert(i,tag_row[i].get_text())
    df.append(list_of_rows,ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

The problem is when I go to print the dataframe, I get this result

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

and I can't understand why.

Comment: Are you convinced that `df.append(list_of_rows,ignore_index=True)` actually ran, and there was interesting content in `list_of_rows`? Use `print` or `pdb.set_trace()`.

Comment: so I switched print(df) to print(list_of_rows) and it printed out basically the entire table, but in reverse order. probably has something to do with the new values being placed at the beginning instead of replacing. So it appears this isn't working the way I think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = df.append(list_of_rows,ignore_index=True)
```

I dont think it appends in place, but instead returns a new df.